# php how to escape text in input textbox

Tags: php, textbox, special-characters

I want to pre-populate an input textbox with text from a database.  However, if the text from the database contains certain special characters such as a `"` mark, it interferes with the html and truncates everything after the quote mark.

Addslashes and also urlencode do not work because the textbox displays the asci text and you just see a slash mark before the quote mark or the encoded text ie `%026`.

Code:

```
<?php

//access data base
while $row=mysql_fetcharray($res) {

$dim =$row['dimension'];

}

echo 'Dimensions: <input type="text" size=20 name="dim" value="'.$dim.'">'; //truncates
echo 'Dimensions: <input type="text" size=20 name="dim" value="'.addslashes($dim).'">'; //shows slashes in textbox
```

?>

Would appreciate any solution to this vexing problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for is [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php):

> Certain characters have special significance in HTML, and should be represented by HTML entities if they are to preserve their meanings.

```
echo 'Dimensions: <input type="text" size=20 name="dim" value="'.htmlspecialchars($dim).'">';
```

Comment: That worked!  Won't let me accept answer for 10 minutes but that did the trick.  Thx!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $str = "Keep the 'quote'.";
    echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
?>
```

Read more: [htmlentities](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)